# My while-loop is not working. When I run it, it always give me infinite output

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have trouble in this while-loop. Everytime I input 'yes' it gives me infinite ouptut. It seems that it skips the "**try:**" section and I don't know why.

```
import random
number = int(random.randint(1, 11))
start = input('Do you wanna play Guess The Number? [Yes] [No]--')
while start.lower() == "yes":
    try:
            num = int('Enter a number within 1-10')
            if int(num) < 1 or int(num) > 10:
                raise ValueError ('Enter a number within the 1-10 only!')
            if int(num) == number:
                print('You got it!')
                break
    except ValueError as err:
            print('Number only!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `num = int('Enter a number within 1-10')` fails, so you get an exception.

You probably mean `num = int(input('Enter a number within 1-10'))`

Answer (score 0):

You **haven't taken the number as input** from the user, instead you are converting a string to int, that's why you are getting exception,

So, first take input from the user then convert it into int

```
 num = int(input('Enter a number within 1-10:'))
```

And the reason for the **infinite loop** is because of you are not changing the value of start. So you need to change the value of start, if the input is not equal to the random numbe.r

Here is the imporved code, hope it makes you understand

```
import random
number = int(random.randint(1, 11))
start = input('Do you wanna play Guess The Number? [Yes] [No]--')
while start.lower() == "yes":
    try:
            num = int(input('Enter a number within 1-10:'))
            if int(num) < 1 or int(num) > 10:
                print('A number should be within the 1-10 only!')
            if int(num) == number:
                print('You got it!')
                break
            else:
                print("Failed to Guess!!!")
                start=input('Do you wanna play Guess The Number? [Yes] [No]--')
    except Exception as err:
            print(err)
```